# Selecting a region with white colour and making the rest of the image black

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm new to Photoshop. I have an image, where I have drawn a shape and filled that shape with a white colour. How can I now make the rest of the image be black?

Answer (score 1):

On the right of the screen you should see a Layers Panel. Create a New Layer, push it to the bottom. Fill it with Black, Fill is in the Edit menu. You have to select it all first... that's in the Select menu.

I'd suggest watching a couple of youtube videos about Photoshop layers, start with this one: [Photoshop CS5: Understanding Layers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhxj4goGtj0)

Comment: The commentary on a design method alternative to use layers is potentially interesting, but it has nothing to do with this question. I have removed it from your answer and all the comments it spawned. Consider posting it as a new question if you'd like a soapbox on why layers are ineffective.

Answer (score -1):

A screenshot might be helpful, but I would select the white with your magic wand tool (to be easy and seeing as you are a PS novice), the go Select > Inverse (this will select the rest of the image). Next Edit > Fill > and from the dropdown select Black.
This is the quickest way.

Comment: I would love to know why this got a -1, he said he didn't understand PS... clearly this is not the method I would use, but sometimes people need to start with their training wheels on.

Comment: Welcome to the community! I didn't downvote but here's a few possible reasons: 1) as we continue to grow more people negate things just to be mean. 2) telling someone a mediocre way because they're a beginner instead of the proper way (admitting this isn't what you would do) could be viewed negatively by some. 3) and perhaps most important being that if the person did in fact draw a shape, and thus a shape layer, your method wouldn't work under current instructions. There's no real certainty unless the person that did down-vote decides to state a reason.